# Least common multiple and greatest common divisor problem.What instruction to use?

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory

Here we have an equation in two variables that involves the greatest common divisor and the least common multiple, I can't think of what else to use.

$$Reduce[(LCM[x, y])^2 + (GCD[x, y])^ 2 == 900]$$
$$Solve[(LCM[x, y])^2 + (GCD[x, y])^ 2 == 900]$$
$$FindInstance[(LCM[x, y])^2 + (GCD[x, y])^ 2 == 900]$$

with no instructions I get something, any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FindInstance[LCM[x,y]^2+GCD[x,y]^2==900&&0<=x<=30,{x,y},Integers]
```

or

```
Reduce[LCM[x,y]^2+GCD[x,y]^2==900&&0<=x<=30&&0<=y<=30,{x,y},Integers]
```

or

```
Solve[LCM[x,y]^2+GCD[x,y]^2==900&&0<=x<=30&&0<=y<=30,{x,y},Integers]
```

or

```
Select[Tuples[{Range[0,30],Range[0,30]}],(LCM@@#)^2+(GCD@@#)^2==900&]
```

Comment: Thanks, In the last example, could you explain to me how the symbols that appear there work, not the instructions, that is to say this
@@ #) ^ 2+ (GCD @@ #) ^ 2 == 900 &]

Comment: Certainly. `Tuples` is going to make a long list of lists of pairs like `{{0,0},{0,1},{0,2}...` `Select` is going to take each of those pairs, one at a time, and do a function to the pair to see whether the result is True or False. So the very first test will be on `{0,0}`. Now we want to perform `LCM[0,0]` but we have to do that given `{0,0}` which is the same as `List[0,0]`. So we need to turn `List[0,0]` into `LCM[0,0]` If you look up `Apply` in the help system it is used to change one function into another. `@@` is the shorthand for `Apply`.  `#` and `&` are shorthand for `Function` OK?

Comment: A different way of writing that last one is `f[{x_,y_}]:=(LCM[x,y])^2+(GCD[x,y])^2==900;
Select[Tuples[{Range[0,30],Range[0,30]}],f]` but that isn't the usual Mathematica "turn anything and everything you can into as few punctuation characters instead of spelled out function names as you possibly can" Does this help a little?

Comment: @ Bill, Thank you very much for your time and explanation